# Differencing Long Memory Time Series

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, differencing, long-range-dependence

I came accross some articles stating that differencing a long memory time series leads to memory loss. I don't know much about long-memory time series, but I know how $ARMA$ and $ARIMA$ processes work. I suppose that "long-memory" means "slowly decaying autocovariances". I would like to have a simple and straightforward mathematical example that shows, starting from a long memory process, how differencing leads to memory loss.